# Close Userform with "X" and exit Excel

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I'm creating a Userform and I want the users to closes the userform through the "X" in the corner and by doing that, I want the Excel to close/exit.
I tryied the UserForm_Deactivate(), but it's not working or calling the UserForm_Deactivate() when "X" is pressed. Heres the code.

```
Private Sub UserForm_Deactivate()
   Application.Quit
End Sub
```

I also tryied Workbooks(1).Close and ActiveWorkbook.Close, none worked.

My userform is named by "Organizador", I don't know if it makes any diference since I tryied Organizador_Deactivate() and nothing happened.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use UserForm_Terminate()

Answer (score 1):

Also if you put "End" in the place of "Application.Quit" it will stop the program and not continue running extra commands in the background that was not completed fully especially if you use "If" functions across "Private Subs" so it will then look like this

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
    End
End Sub
```